# Count something FROM database

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone explain me what it's wrong with that part of code?

```
$count_query_v1 = 'COUNT user_id FROM  stiri WHERE user_id = '.$_SESSION["user"]["nume"].''; 
$answer = mysql_query($count_query_v1) or die(mysql_error()); 
echo $answer;
```

Return me that error:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT user_id FROM stiri WHERE user_id = John' at line 1**

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT count (user_id)....`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a select, and some parenthesis. This should work:

```
SELECT count(user_id) FROM stiri WHERE user_id = '.$_SESSION["user"]["nume"]
```

Read [the documentation about COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html). Also, your script is **vulnerable** to SQL Injection. I recommend you to also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) on how to prevent it.

Comment: Please also suggest fixing the SQL vulnerability

Comment: @ExplosionPills, done, and linked to the documentation.

Comment: If you are going to add any other items to the select, don't forget to name the count as a variable so it's more easily accessible to PHP